# How to deal with divide by zero error in sql

Tags: sql, null, zero, nullif

I'm new to SQL and would like to know the best way of dealing with dividing by zeros. I know about the NULLIF function however I'm having a bit of trouble implementing it.

In this example, every field could be a zero. What is the best way of going about solving this; should we just check if the whole expression equates to zero or do some sort of check for each field in mu expression?

```
 SELECT             
        round(Sum((SOI.CurItemValue + SOI.CurTaxValue) / NULLIF(SOI.Quantity,0) * NULLIF(SOI.QuantityOutstanding,0)),2) 
        FROM SalesOrderItems SOI
```

With this current code I get `Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Comment: I don't know about the error but when using nullif in a division like that why not have `NULLIF(SOI.Quantity,1)` instead to avoid division by zero?

Comment: @Fusiozii Using `NULLIF` to avoid the divide by zero error is correct way to go. Just put a check on your denominator to avoid having zeros.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but why not just add a `WHERE SOI.Quantity > 0`?

Comment: Cheers guys all good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CASE to calculate only if the Quantity greater than 0. Check this query :

```
SELECT             
    CASE WHEN SOI.Quantity=0 THEN 0
         ELSE ROUND( Sum( (SOI.CurItemValue + SOI.CurTaxValue) / SOI.Quantity  * SOI.QuantityOutstanding ),2) END OutstandingValue
FROM SalesOrderItems SOI
```